# tinymce is undefined

Tags: javascript, asp.net, tinymce

I'm trying to use tinymce in an ASP.NET content page.   The code works when I run it in VisualStudio2008.  When I deploy it to IIS I get a javascript error 'Error: 'tinyMCE' is undefined'

```
<script src="tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
tinyMCE.init({
        // General options
        mode : "textareas",
        theme : "advanced",
        plugins : "autolink,lists,spellchecker,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template",

        // Theme options
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
        theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
        theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,spellchecker,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,blockquote,pagebreak,|,insertfile,insertimage",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
        theme_advanced_resizing : true,

        // Skin options
        skin : "o2k7",
        skin_variant : "silver",

        // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
        content_css : "css/example.css",

        // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
        template_external_list_url : "js/template_list.js",
        external_link_list_url : "js/link_list.js",
        external_image_list_url : "js/image_list.js",
        media_external_list_url : "js/media_list.js",

        // Replace values for the template plugin
        template_replace_values : {
                username : "Some User",
                staffid : "991234"
        }
});
</script>


<textarea id="txtareaEmailEditor" name="content" rows="30" cols="100" runat="server" ></textarea>
```

**EDIT:**  I ran firebug and looked under the net tab and it had

**`GET tiny_mce.js  503 Service Unavailable`**

**UPDATE** I moved the script to the application folder and that got rid of the 503 error but I still get the tinymce undefined error.

```
<script src="tiny_mce.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

here's my address in IIS
http://svr-app-d1/MailServiceWeb/EmailTemplateEditor.aspx

---

**I got some help from a senior dev here and he made these changes and it works now
IIS -> ASP  EnableParentPaths=true
IIS -> Handler Mappings StaticFile enabled**

Comment: What is the URL of the page you are visiting in IIS, and where is the `tinymce` folder located relative to your site's root directory?

Comment: I moved the script to the application folder and that got rid of the 503 error but I still get the tinymce undefined error.

<script src="tiny_mce.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

here's my address in IIS http://svr-app-d1/MailServiceWeb/EmailTemplateEditor.aspx

Comment: See my updated answer below. Again, you need to make the path to tiny_mce.js absolute, which you still haven't done. You did *not* need to move it to the application top level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got some help from a senior dev here and he made these changes and it works now IIS -> ASP EnableParentPaths=true IIS -> Handler Mappings StaticFile enabled

Answer (score 2):

The path `tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js` is relative to the page you are viewing. So, when you are viewing it locally, you are probably viewing it from a different path in IIS. Try using an absolute path instead:

```
/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js
```

**Updated answer after updated question:**

> I moved the script to the application folder ... `<script src="tiny_mce.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` My address in IIS is `svr-app-d1/MailServiceWeb/EmailTemplateEditor.aspx`

Use `<script src="/tiny_mce.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` instead. Notice the `/` at the front. This makes the path absolute.

Explanation:

When you accessed your page at `svr-app-d1/MailServiceWeb/EmailTemplateEditor.aspx`, it was looking for `tiny_mce.js` within the `MailServiceWeb` directory (which, as you know, is incorrect).

Comment: When I add the "/" at the beginning I get a 503 error in firebug.  When i leave it out I get "Failed to load source for: http://svr-app-d1/MailServiceWeb/tiny_mce.js"

Comment: Try visiting /tiny_mce.js directly within your browser. Does it come up? Do you get a 503 error?

Comment: In firefox i get the download prompt, so I went ahead and saved it and them opened the file and it was empty

Comment: Sounds like an IIS problem. What version of IIS are you using? You will need to [check your IIS logs](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/windowsserver2003/library/iis/55f71614-ef1b-4015-b9c8-a42c1e700c25.mspx?mfr=true) to see why the 503 error is occurring.

Comment: We're using IIS version 6.0 on Windows Server 2008 Standard

Comment: So what does the IIS log message say? Did you check http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/windowsserver2003/library/iis/55f71614-ef1b-4015-b9c8-a42c1e700c25.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to view the log files.  I'll update the post if I find anything